# How do I target the 3rd entry and only that entry?

Tags: templating, entry, index

I am trying to build an `Index` page and assign a specific `card` template to the `3rd entry` and only the `3rd entry`.

```
{% set items = craft.entries.section('posts').all() %}

{% for cardC in items.offset(2).limit(1) %}

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-raised card-background" style="background-image: url('{{ cardC.postImage.one().getUrl() }}')">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-category text-info">Marketing</h6>
                <h3 class="card-title">{{ cardC.title }}</h3>
                <p class="card-description">
                   {{ cardC.introParagraph }}
                </p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-round">
                    <i class="material-icons">subject</i> Read Case Study
                </a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-white btn-just-icon btn-link" title="" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Save to Pocket">
                    <i class="fa fa-get-pocket"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

I also tried `{% for cardC in items.nth(3 )%}`.

I get the following `**error message**`:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("offset") on an array.

I created the `set` because I need to apply templates for the other entries, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you apply `.all()`, the variable you're working with becomes an array. Which means that the `.offset(2)` needs to be applied *before* you convert it into an array.

---

**UPDATE**

As @andrew.welch points out in the comments, it's as easy as grabbing the third item in your array...

```
items[2]
```

Ultimately, it looks like you want something like this...

```
{% set cardC = items[2] %}

{% if cardC %}

    {# ... the rest of your code #}

{% endif %}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Once it's an array, you'll need to use the [Twig syntax](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) instead...

```
items[2:1]
```

Which translates to: "get third item (0-based index), limit of one".

Comment: should I keep the .all()?

Comment: You mentioned that you set `items` in order to render multiple entries. If so, then yes... That said, _don't_ apply the offset & limit before the `all` if you intend to use `items` for multiple entries.

Comment: Do we need `slice` here? Seems like it could just be `items[2]` no?

Comment: Ahh, good call @andrew.welch! Even I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly.